# Phalcon ExecuteQuery inner Join issues

Tags: phalcon

This is Native SQL Query, thats work in MySql:

```
SELECT a.pshdQty
FROM production_stock_header a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(pshdId) AS pshdId
FROM production_stock_header
WHERE pshdAuditDelete = 'N'
) b
ON a.pshdId = b.pshdId
```

But, why in Phalcon this always errors?

```
$triggerSet = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("
                    SELECT  pshdQty
                    FROM ProductionStockHeader  
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(pshdId) AS pshdId
                    FROM ProductionStockHeader
                    WHERE ProductionStockHeader.AuditDelete = 'N'
                    ) AS b
                    ON ProductionStockHeader.pshdId = b.pshdId
                ");
```

Comment: Phalcon ORM just don't support queries like this, just inner join ProductionStockHeader and where statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phalcon ORM doesn't provide a way to write such `join` statements.
I'd suggest to just run a raw *native SQL* query on your db connection:

```
$triggerSet = $this->db->query("SELECT a.pshdQty
        FROM production_stock_header a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(pshdId) AS pshdId
            FROM production_stock_header
            WHERE pshdAuditDelete = 'N'
        ) b
        ON a.pshdId = b.pshdId")->fetch();
```

`$this->db` points to your database connection you registered in your services.

You can also drop the inner join all together:

```
$triggerSet = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("
    SELECT pshdQty
    FROM ProductionStockHeader
    WHERE AuditDelete = 'N'
    ORDER BY pshdId DESC
    LIMIT 1
");
```

Comment: How can i get the results?
when i vardump it doesnt show the results, thx

Comment: @codeK.O., if you try the 2nd solution, won't that be easier? It should give you the same result

Comment: im phalcon new comer, and before this im using codeigniter..
the 2nd solutions have a bug when the records data become bigger..
it cannot fetch till the end, so sometimes if im using ORDER BY DESC, it doesnt get the last results.

Comment: @codeK.O. What do you mean with `it doesnt get the last results`. I doubt MySQL would randomly drop your records. Do you mean the column `pshId` isn't ordering your data correctly?

Comment: in short answer is : yes.. i dont know why.. but it happens in my last project.

Comment: maybe a stupid question but; your `pshId` column is of a `numeric` type, right? If it were a string, it would indeed cause problems when sorting.

Comment: yes, it auto increment, so it must be int (numeric)..
i don't know why it happens too.. first time i use it and the records still small it works fine, but while the records getting bigger it has bug..

Comment: I still would just remade your statement for working with PHQL, it can be done, also use query builder :)

Just join whole ProductionStockHeader and use where ?